# PHP JPGRAPH - omitting individual datapoints

Tags: php, jpgraph

Quick question, I retrieve data from an SQL DB and want to scale it to a customised time range for a line graph. Now the data may not always fill this new scale nicely, hence the line may drop to zero and then ping back up to some random value. Is there a predefined value or similar to force Jpgraph to jump that datapoint and just connect the line with the next 'existing' datapoint.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From jpgraph manual](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch13s06.html):

Ignore the data point and connect the previous and next data point with the line in a line graph. This is accomplished by specifying the null value as

'-' - A single hyphen character

Comment: Thanks, been a small while since I checked this thread... but youre right :)